# MySQL - Count the maximum number of count that a row has repeated

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this data in my database.

```
id  | company_id |     referrer
001 | 001        | https://google.com
002 | 001        | https://riot.com
003 | 001        | https://google.com
004 | 002        | https://vimeo.com
005 | 002        | https://yahoo.com
006 | 003        | https://yahoo.com
```

I want to get the number of times a referrer has repeated per company_id. A company has many referrer, but I only want to get the highest referrer that repeated in the data.

So the result would be something like this:

```
company_id | referrer           | nRepeat
001        | https://google.com |  2
002        | https://yahoo.com  |  2
```

I tried this code:

```
SELECT company_id,
       referrer,
       Count(referrer) AS viewCount
FROM   `my_table`
GROUP  BY company_id
ORDER  BY viewcount DESC
```

This query seems to be wrong.

Apologies if I explain it poorly, let me know if you have questions.

Any tips or help on this? Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In group by use company_id as well

Comment: GROUP  BY company_id,referrer

Comment: why compid for https://riot.com and https://google.com is same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT company_id, referrer, COUNT(*) viewCount,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY company_id, referrer
)

SELECT company_id, referrer, viewCount
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Here is the above written as a single select, sans the use of a CTE:

```sql
SELECT company_id, referrer, viewCount
FROM
(
    SELECT company_id, referrer, COUNT(*) viewCount,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY company_id, referrer
) t
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Here is a version which should work on MySQL versions earlier than 8+:

```sql
SELECT company_id, referrer, COUNT(*) viewCount
FROM my_table t1
GROUP BY company_id, referrer
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM my_table t2
                   WHERE t2.company_id = t1.company_id
                   GROUP BY referrer
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! Is there a simpler way to do this without using `WITH cte ...`  Like a subquery? Might be difficult to integrate this in Laravel.

Comment: I have given you a version which does not use a CTE.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late. I had to try it on our live server as I have access to it just today. I tried it on my local server and seems to work perfectly, but when I had to upload it in our live server, I am getting this error:
```Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk```

Might have to do with MySQL Version?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower Yes it is probably your MySQL version.  I have given you a workaround.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I tested your workaround and I noticed that the company_id is repeating. Should it not repeat because we are only getting the most occurrence of `referral` per company? Here is a screenshot that it is repeating - https://www.screencast.com/t/yEn9YWZarB

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't help, because I can't see the data.

Comment: Oh, as you can see in the screenshot, there is a repeating number under the `company_id` column. I intentionally cut the URL data as those are confidential. Here's another screenshot, but I blur the referal data. https://www.screencast.com/t/UxTLkhAC9YoR

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/W20aoRuoeUq - this screenshot shows that `company_id` `123` has repeated.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong here.  The apparent duplicates all have the same view count.  If you only want to return one, then you need additional logic.

Comment: Hi, I know this is not part of the question, but do you know how to make the query fast? I have 2.5M rows in that table and executing the query makes the connection time out. Just hoping that you have other ideas on this. Thanks.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower You can try adding an index on `(referrer, company_id)`.